# Android - GroundOverlay size (application crash)

Tags: android

I am trying to show the image via GroundOverlay in my Android application. I am using this code:

```
BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_image);
    GroundOverlay groundArc = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
            .image(image)
            .transparency(0.1f)
            .position(point1));
```

This works fine but when I try to draw the image which has 1230 x 1539 resolution and 292 kB, application crashed when started. In original, this image is big as Europe.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the Crash Log / Stacktrace (from logcat)

Comment: The logcat don't show any informations.

Comment: From the resolution you posted alone, that image is way too big. You'll probably have to scale and crop it down to size.

Comment: I have problem with imagecrop, because I need to download images from Internet and show on map. Like NOAA weather images.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?